# How to display different column elements on X-Axis and Group in different column for xScale in D3.js Version 5

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

The data which we are using is having 2 main category column i.e ID and Desc. For example Region_ID, Region_Desc.

Earlier in the code I was using **Region_Desc** to group it in xScale and display in X-Axis.

But facing issue when the underline data have duplicate descriptions but distinct IDs (for whatever reason).
So, to resolve the issue I thought to group the data in xScale using **Region_ID** but display **Region_Desc** on X-Axis.

```
const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(barData.map(d => d.Region_ID))
      .range([0, width+margin.right]);
```

And for displaying on X-Axis:

```
const bars = svgG.selectAll('g.bar')
        .data(barData)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
      .classed('bar', true)
      .attr('transform', d => `translate(${xScale(d.Region_Desc) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2}, 0)`);
```

I am not able to achieve the same. How can I do that?

**Edited**

Below is the sample screenshot of the required chart out of the data provided:
[image]

Below is the code:

```js
        const barData = [{
        "Region_ID":1,
        "Region_Desc": "Region1",
        "Value": 538865
        },
        {
        "Region_ID":2,
        "Region_Desc": "Region2",
        "Value": 645375
        },
        {
        "Region_ID":3,
        "Region_Desc": "Region3",
        "Value": 434535
        },
        {
        "Region_ID":4,
        "Region_Desc": "Region4",
        "Value": 734595
        },
        {
        "Region_ID": 5,
        "Region_Desc": "Region5",
        "Value": 834545
        },
        {
        "Region_ID": 6,
        "Region_Desc": "Region6",
        "Value": 534555
        },
        {
        "Region_ID": 7,
        "Region_Desc": "Region1",
        "Value": 634565
        },
        {
        "Region_ID":8,
        "Region_Desc": "Region2",
        "Value": 33455
        }
        ];
            const container = d3.select('#graph');
          const divWidth = parseInt(container.style('width'));
            const divHeight = parseInt(container.style('height'));

        // Consider this width and Height are dynamic for div "graphID" because I am trying to responsive design
            const margin = {top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50};
          const width = divWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
          const height = divHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                //To add svg in the visualization node i.e Dome node                    
         const svg = container.append("svg")
           .attr("width", divWidth)
           .attr("height", divHeight);
              
         const svgG = svg.append("g")
           .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);
           
           //To add tooltip for bar
           var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");
          
          const defs = svg.append("defs");
          
          const marker = defs.append("marker")
          .attr("id","arrowhead")
          .attr("markerWidth","10")
           .attr("markerHeight","7")
           .attr("refX","0")
           .attr("refY","3.5")
           .attr("orient","auto")
           
           const polygon = marker.append("polygon")
           .attr("fill","gray")
           .attr("points","0 0, 10 3.5, 0 7")
                
        const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
          .domain(barData.map(d => d.Region_ID))
          .range([0, width+margin.right]);

        const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
                
        //Adding g attribute to svg for x axis
        svgG.append('g')
            .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`) 
            .call(xAxis);
                
        const yAxisMax = barData.reduce((max, item) => Math.max(max, item.Value), 0) * 1.5;
                
        const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, yAxisMax])
            .range([height, 0]);

        const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(4);
                
        svgG.append('g')
            .call(yAxis);

        const bars = svgG.selectAll('g.bar')
            .data(barData)
            .enter()
            .append('g')
          .classed('bar', true)
          .attr('transform', d => `translate(${xScale(d.Region_Desc) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2}, 0)`);
        /*  
        const staticColor =   "steelblue",
        highlightColor = "orange";

        var sheet = document.createElement('style')
        sheet.innerHTML = ".bar {fill: "+staticColor+"} .highlight {fill:"+highlightColor+"}";
        document.body.appendChild(sheet);
        */
        bars.append('rect')
            .attr('x', -20)
            .attr('width', 40)
            .attr('y', d =>  yScale(d.Value))
            .attr('height', d => height - yScale(d.Value) )
            .attr('fill', 'blue')
            //.attr("class", "bar")
            .on("mousemove", onMouseOver)
                    .on("mouseout", onMouseOut);
                
        function onMouseOver(d,i)
        {
                    tooltip
                      .style("left", d3.event.pageX - 50 + "px")
                      .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 70 + "px")
                      .style("display", "inline-block")
                      .html("Year: " + (d.Region_Desc) + "<br>" + "Value: " + (d.Value));
                      d3.select(this).attr('fill', "#eec42d");
                      //d3.select(this).attr('class', 'highlight');
                      //this.setState({ fillColour: 'green' });


        }

        function onMouseOut(d,i)
        {
         tooltip.style("display", "none");
         d3.select(this).attr('fill', "blue");
         //d3.select(this).attr('class', 'bar');
         //this.setState({ fillColour: 'blue' });
        }
              
        bars.append('text')
            .text(d => d.Value)
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .attr('y', d => yScale(d.Value))
          .attr('dy', -5)
         ;

        bars.filter((d, i) => i < barData.length - 1)
        .append('path')
           .attr('d', (d, i) => `M 5,${yScale(d.Value) - 20} V ${Math.min(yScale(d.Value), yScale(barData[i + 1].Value)) - 60} H ${xScale.bandwidth() - 5} V ${yScale(barData[i + 1].Value) - 25}`)
        .style('stroke', 'gray')
        .style('fill', 'none')
        .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)')

        bars.filter((d, i) => i < barData.length - 1)
          .append('rect')
          .attr('x', 15)
          .attr('y', (d, i) => Math.min(yScale(d.Value), yScale(barData[i + 1].Value)) - 70)
          .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth() - 30)
          .attr('height', 20)
          .attr('rx', 10)
          .style('fill', 'white')
          .style('stroke', 'gray');

        bars.filter((d, i) => i < barData.length - 1)
          .append('text')
          .text((d, i) => `${barData[i + 1].Value > d.Value ? '+' : ''}${Math.round((barData[i + 1].Value / d.Value * 100) - 100)}%`)
          .attr('x', xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
          .attr('y', (d, i) => Math.min(yScale(d.Value), yScale(barData[i + 1].Value)) - 56)
          .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
          .style('fill', 'black');
```

```css
#graph {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}

text {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
}

.toolTip {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  min-width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #6F257F;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="graph">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can avoid duplicate descriptions since you have to display every item with distinct ID and set its position by ID... You can, however, sort the items by description, and render one description for a group of items

Comment: Hmm.. My Bad, I think I didn't make the requirement clear. I have edited the post with the image which is required from the data which available in code.  Basically if there is a duplicate description column even though it should come as a different bar because the ID is different. Please have a look at the edited post and please let me know if anything can be done?

Comment: Can't we do anything for this requirement? It seems to be a generic issue which someone may face at some point of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some many google search and trial. Finally I found the solution for the issue which I was facing.
Below is the code which I used:

```
var xAxisData = [];
for(i=0;i<barData.length;i++)
{
    xAxisData.push(barData[i].Region_Desc);
  //console.log(barData[i].Region_Desc);
}

const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
.domain(barData.map(d => d.Region_ID))
.range([0, width+margin.right]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
.tickFormat((d,i) => xAxisData[i]);
```

And below is the complete working code:

```js
        const barData = [{
        "Region_ID":1,
        "Region_Desc": "Region1",
        "Value": 538869
        },
        {
        "Region_ID":2,
        "Region_Desc": "Region2",
        "Value": 645375
        },
        {
        "Region_ID":3,
        "Region_Desc": "Region3",
        "Value": 434535
        },
        {
        "Region_ID":4,
        "Region_Desc": "Region4",
        "Value": 734595
        },
        {
        "Region_ID": 5,
        "Region_Desc": "Region5",
        "Value": 834545
        },
        {
        "Region_ID": 6,
        "Region_Desc": "Region6",
        "Value": 534555
        },
        {
        "Region_ID": 7,
        "Region_Desc": "Region1",
        "Value": 634565
        },
        {
        "Region_ID":8,
        "Region_Desc": "Region2",
        "Value": 33459
        }
        ];
            const container = d3.select('#graph');
          const divWidth = parseInt(container.style('width'));
            const divHeight = parseInt(container.style('height'));

        // Consider this width and Height are dynamic for div "graphID" because I am trying to responsive design
            const margin = {top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50};
          const width = divWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
          const height = divHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                //To add svg in the visualization node i.e Dome node                    
         const svg = container.append("svg")
           .attr("width", divWidth)
           .attr("height", divHeight);
              
         const svgG = svg.append("g")
           .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);
           
           //To add tooltip for bar
           var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");
         
     var xAxisData = [];
        for(i=0;i<barData.length;i++)
    {
        xAxisData.push(barData[i].Region_Desc);
      //console.log(barData[i].Region_Desc);
    }
   //console.log(xAxisData);
        const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
          .domain(barData.map(d => d.Region_ID))
          .range([0, width+margin.right]);

        const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
    .tickFormat((d,i) => xAxisData[i]);
                
        //Adding g attribute to svg for x axis
        const xAxisG = svgG.append('g')
            .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`) 
            .call(xAxis);
      
   /* xAxisG.selectAll('.tick').each(function() {
                      const tick = d3.select(this);
                      const text = tick.select('text').text();
                      //const data = barData.find(d => d.Region_ID === text);
                      
                    tick.select('text').style('fill', 'black');
          tick.select('text').attr('value',d => d.Region_Desc)
                    //tick.select('text').attr('y',-15)
                    //tick.select('line').style('stroke', 'white');
                    //tick.select('text').style('dy',height/2 -10);
                      
                    }) 
          */
                
        const yAxisMax = barData.reduce((max, item) => Math.max(max, item.Value), 0) * 1.5;
                
        const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, yAxisMax])
            .range([height, 0]);

        const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(4);
                
        svgG.append('g')
            .call(yAxis);

        const bars = svgG.selectAll('g.bar')
            .data(barData)
            .enter()
            .append('g')
          .classed('bar', true)
          .attr('transform', d => `translate(${xScale(d.Region_ID) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2}, 0)`);

        bars.append('rect')
            .attr('x', -20)
            .attr('width', 40)
            .attr('y', d =>  yScale(d.Value))
            .attr('height', d => height - yScale(d.Value) )
            .attr('fill', 'blue')
            //.attr("class", "bar")
            .on("mousemove", onMouseOver)
                    .on("mouseout", onMouseOut);
        
              
        bars.append('text')
            .text(d => d.Value)
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .attr('y', d => yScale(d.Value))
          .attr('dy', -5);
     
     
            
        function onMouseOver(d,i)
        {
                    tooltip
                      .style("left", d3.event.pageX - 50 + "px")
                      .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 70 + "px")
                      .style("display", "inline-block")
                      .html("Year: " + (d.Region_Desc) + "<br>" + "Value: " + (d.Value));
                      d3.select(this).attr('fill', "#eec42d");
                      //d3.select(this).attr('class', 'highlight');
                      //this.setState({ fillColour: 'green' });


        }

        function onMouseOut(d,i)
        {
         tooltip.style("display", "none");
         d3.select(this).attr('fill', "blue");
         //d3.select(this).attr('class', 'bar');
         //this.setState({ fillColour: 'blue' });
        }
```

```css
#graph {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}

text {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
}

.toolTip {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  min-width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #6F257F;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="graph">
</div>
```